# Python inline if when setting variable

Tags: java, python, inline

In Java, setting a variable to a value based on a condition could be done in one line 
like so:

```
variable = (!true) ? 1 : 2
```

This would result to '2'.

Is there python equivalent to this code?

Thank you.

Comment: For future reference, this is known as the ternary operator. That term should be much more search-friendly than "inline if".

Comment: Given that `!true` is a constant, the easiest way to write this in one line is `variable = 2`. :)

Comment: @user2357112: Actually, in Python, it's called a "conditional expression", and `if` is explicitly _not_ an operator. However, after a bit of resistance, they relented and added `sometimes called a "ternary operator"` to [the docs](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) because that's what everyone coming from C-family languages searches for.

Comment: @abarnert That was just an example. The conditional in there can be anything.

Comment: @Yoni201: I was pretty sure of that, which is why I put it as a comment (with a stupid smiley) rather than an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
variable =  1 if not True else 2
```

General ternary syntax:

```
<value_if_true> if <condition> else <value_if_false>
```

This is called a [conditional expression](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) in Python, and is mostly equivalent to the "ternary operator" in C-family languages (although it's not actually an operator). The original proposal [PEP 308](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0308/) has more details.